# Parse json responce

Tags: php, json

I have been trying to read the json response of this below URL

```
https://partner-int-api.groupon.com/deals.json?country_code=IN&tsToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&CID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&nlp&utm_source=GPN&utm_medium=afl&utm_campaign=200321
```

or [**click here**](https://partner-int-api.groupon.com/deals.json?country_code=IN&tsToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&CID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&nlp&utm_source=GPN&utm_medium=afl&utm_campaign=200321) to access it.

I want to get the

```
"price": {
   "amount": 49900,
   "formattedAmount": "Rs.499.00",
   "currencyCode": "INR"
}
```

How to read this ?

```
foreach($datas as $d)
{

    $list.= "<div class=frew>";         
    $list.= "<a href='".$d->dealUrl."'>".$d->announcementTitle."</a>";
    $list.= "<div>";
    $list.= "<div style='float:left;width:90%'><img src='".$d->mediumImageUrl."' />";
    $list.= "<div style='padding-left:2px;float:left'>".$d->title."
    <a class=css-button href='".$d->dealUrl."'>Click Here</a>   </br>
    <strong>Popularity: <a href='".$d->dealUrl."'> $d->soldQuantity </a></strong></br>
    </div></div>"; 
    $list.= "</div>";
    $list.= "</div>";

}
```

Comment: `json_decode`: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I am not a PHP guy... to read and understand.. can someone tell me what to edit in my each loop ? Thanks.

Comment: @apptikka Your data doesn't align with what your output is.  Not sure what you want from us...

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the URL that returns [json](/questions/tagged/json) output, you will need, *mainly*, two PHP functions:

- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

So, you can do something like the following:

```
<?php
$q = "https://partner-int-api.groupon.com/deals.json?country_code=IN&tsToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&CID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&nlp&utm_source=GPN&utm_medium=afl&utm_campaign=200321";
function readQuery($q){     
        $data = file_get_contents($q);
        return json_decode($data);
    }

echo "<pre>";
$res = readQuery($q);
$i = 0;
foreach ($res->deals as $deal){
    foreach ($deal->options as $option){
        $prices[$i]['amount'] = $option->price->amount;
        $prices[$i]['formattedAmount'] = $option->price->formattedAmount;
        $prices[$i]['currencyCode'] = $option->price->currencyCode;

    }
    $i++;
}
//var_dump($res->deals[1]->options[1]->price);
print_r($prices);
```

The above solution will return an array that holds all prices in your JSON resource.

Comment: just now i googled and find the api response and parsed that. But before you posted. cheers man..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$data` already has the content from the JSON file you have linked to:

```
$json = json_decode($data);
foreach ($json->deals as $deal) {
    $list.= "<div class=frew>";
    $list.= "<a href='".$deal->dealUrl."'>".$deal->announcementTitle."</a>";
    $list.= "<div>";
    $list.= "<div style='float:left;width:90%'><img src='".$deal->mediumImageUrl."' />";
    $list.= "<div style='padding-left:2px;float:left'>".$deal->title."
        <a class=css-button href='".$deal->dealUrl."'>Click Here</a>   </br>
        <strong>Popularity: <a href='".$deal->dealUrl."'> $d->soldQuantity </a></strong></br>
        </div></div>";
    $list.= "</div>";
    $list.= "</div>";
}
```

You can then echo out $list to see the item.